# On Windows 7 how do you remove programs that add themselves to the right click menu?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, mercurial, tortoise-hg

After installing Tortoisehg workbench whenever I right click on an icon or the desktop on the menu it has options for Hg Workbench and Tortoisehg. I don't want that, how do I get rid of it? By the way, what is that feature called? I thought it's referred to as shell integration but after I googled the phrase it only came up with the calculus shell integration.
[image: example]

Comment: just a note....some applications allow you to add/remove shell ext items in their options/prefs. Winrar has this feature, not sure if those displayed have the same options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's often called "shell integration", and is done by *shell extensions* ("shell" referring to Explorer, the graphical shell of Windows).

One program that lets you disable individual shell extensions is [Nirsoft ShExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html).

[image]

Comment: If he has CCleaner, there are options in that program to do the same thing.